# Implement UITextFieldDelegate methods inside a protocol

Tags: ios

I would like to know if/ how can I implement the UITextFieldDelegate methods inside a protocol. I am using Swift language. I want to achieve the next functionality. Implement the text field delegate methods inside a protocol, and implement that protocol by multiple different classes.

I wish to know if possible, and how (an example).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

This is called [Protocol Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID280). Example:

```
protocol YourProtocol: UITextFieldDelegate {
    // protocol definition goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done this and implemented the textFieldDelegate methods inside. Then, I conform to the "YourProtocol" in a customCell I've created. Inside the I have a textField and in awakeFromNib method (inside the cell) i set the cell as delegate for the textField. As I said above, the cell is conforming to the protocol but, the textField delegate methods inside the protocol are not trigered when action on the textField( startEditing, endEditing, etc.). I also have to mention that I've declared the textFIeld as a property in the protocol too.